# Removing hidden data and "personal information" from '.doc' , '.docx' and '.pptx' documents

Tags: powershell, ms-word

Hi I am trying to remove the 'hidden data' and personal information set for '.doc, .docx, .pptx' documments through powershell :
HEre is the powershell script which I have written for the same :

```
$path = "C:\Users\anisjain\Documents\GRR Production\HiddenProrerties" 
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
$xlRemoveDocType = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.xlRDIRemovePersonalInformation" -as [type] 
$wordFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.doc, *.docx -recurse 
$objword = New-Object -ComObject word.application 

foreach($obj in $wordFiles) 
{ 
$documents = $MSWord.Documents.Open($obj.fullname) 
"Removing document information from $obj" 
$documents.RemoveDocumentInformation($xlRemoveDocType::xlRDIRemovePersonalInformation) 
$documents.Save() 
$objword.documents.close() 
} 
$objword.Quit()
```

This however, doesnt work. Can someone please tell me where am i going wrong? 
and if there is some other way of doing it. I have around 2000 records from which i wish to remove the 'hidden document information'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"?

Comment: Does $xlRemoveDocType::xlRDIRemovePersonalInformation evaluate to 4 ? (strictly, I suppose you should use the equivalent Word constants, but in many if not all cases they seem to have the same value as the Excel ones)

Answer (score 4):

here's the script that works for me, after some googling/copying/modifying

```
$path = "d:\rubbish\myfolder\"
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
$WdRemoveDocType = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRemoveDocInfoType" -as [type] 
$wordFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.doc, *.docx -recurse 
$objword = New-Object -ComObject word.application 
$objword.visible = $false 

foreach($obj in $wordFiles) 
{ 
    $documents = $objword.Documents.Open($obj.fullname) 
    "Removing document information from $obj" 
    # WdRemoveDocInfoType Enumeration Reference
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdremovedocinfotype(v=office.14).aspx
    # 99 = WdRDIAll
    #$documents.RemoveDocumentInformation(99)
    $documents.RemoveDocumentInformation($WdRemoveDocType::wdRDIAll) 
    $documents.Save() 
    $objword.documents.close() 
} 
$objword.Quit()
```